# Confusion about definition of least upper bound

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, supremum-and-infimum

I'm learning set theory and I got to bounded sets. I got to the following definition and I have a question about it:

[image]

The problem that I have is the quantified variable $a$. If I would write the quantified statement down it would look like this: $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{N}, \exists a \in A, M - \epsilon < a$. **My question is** wouldn't the right quantified variable $a$ be a $\forall$ as well, like this: $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{N}, \forall a \in A, M - \epsilon < a$. Now, with the definition from the book, I'm not fully targetting all of the elements of $A$, ***as I actually should*** since a least lower bound is targetting the whole set. **So the question is**, which version is right, mine or the one from the book ?

Comment: "as I actually should"  No.  You should not.  There are two aspects of least upper bound.  The "upper bound aspect", that does target all $\alpha \in A$.  ANd the *least* aspect which most certainly does *NOT* target all elements of $A$.  In fact it doesn't target *any* elements of $A$.  As lest upper bound its target are the REAL NUMBERS (nothing to do with $A$) that are all smaller than $M$.  What is is saying is "$\forall w; w< M;w$ is not upper bound.  Now its the target of $w$, *not* of $M$, that is the elments of $A$. Namely $w$ is *not* u.b. so $\exists a\in A; w< a$......

Comment: The actual statement is twofold  i) $\forall a\in A: a \le M$.  (that is "$M$ is an upper bound") and ii) $\forall w\in \mathbb R, w<M: \exists a\in A, w< a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to the definition:

- Upper bound: $\forall a\in A, a \le M$
- Least: $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists a \in A, M - \epsilon < a$

For the "least" part, it might help to think of an equivalent statement:
$\forall \epsilon>0, \lnot(\forall a \in A, M - \epsilon \ge a)$, which says that $M - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound.  That is, there is no upper bound smaller than $M$.

Comment: I understood that. The problem that I have is with how the variable $a$ has been quantified. My problem is understanding why the variable $a$ has been quantified the way it is. Shouldn't the variable $a$ be quantified with a $\forall$ as well ? So $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{N}, \forall a \in A, M - \epsilon < a$ ?

Comment: No, the $\forall a$ goes only with the upper bound part.  Also, note that $\epsilon >0$ (any positive real number), not $\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I added a little bit of explanation that might help.

Comment: The least upper bound of $(0,1)$ is $1$. Why? Because for all $a\in A$ we have $a\le 1$ and for all $\epsilon >0$ the number $1-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound. Let's test that for $\epsilon =0.1$. Is $0.9$ an upper bound? No, because **there exists** $a\in A$  ($0.95$ is an example) such that $a \not\le 0.9$. It just isn't true (or relevant) that all elements $a \in A$ satisfy $a \not\le 0.9$.